# Counting and summing in multiple columns in r and storing in new columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(
  did= c(109,109,201,521,521,521,111,111,111,111),
  dname=c("A","A","B","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
  bid=c(5252,5252,6633,4455,4455,4455,8989,8989,8990,8990),
  bname=c("A1","A1","B1","C1","C1","C1","D1","D1","D2","D2"),
  rname=c("AK","AK","RA","RK","RK","RK","PK","PK","AP","AP"),
  pid=c(65488,65488,54654,68745,68745,68745,32485,32485,87891,87891),
  count=c(5,4,6,10,2,6,4,8,11,5))

> df
   did dname  bid bname rname   pid count
1  109     A 5252    A1    AK 65488     5
2  109     A 5252    A1    AK 65488     4
3  201     B 6633    B1    RA 54654     6
4  521     C 4455    C1    RK 68745    10
5  521     C 4455    C1    RK 68745     2
6  521     C 4455    C1    RK 68745     6
7  111     D 8989    D1    PK 32485     4
8  111     D 8989    D1    PK 32485     8
9  111     D 8990    D2    AP 87891    11
10 111     D 8990    D2    AP 87891     5
```

**The output that I need is like this:**

```
df.out<-data.frame(
  did=c(109,201,521,111,111),
  dname=c("A","A","C","D","D"),
  bid=c(5252,6633,4455,8989,8990),
  bname=c("A1","B1","C1","D1","D2"),
  rname=c("AK","RA","RK","PK","AP"),
  pcount=c(2,1,3,2,2),
  new_count=c(9,6,1,8,16))

> df.out
  did dname  bid bname rname pcount new_count
1 109     A 5252    A1    AK      2         9
2 201     A 6633    B1    RA      1         6
3 521     C 4455    C1    RK      3         1
4 111     D 8989    D1    PK      2         8
5 111     D 8990    D2    AP      2        16
```

So in the output we are counting counting pids and saving it in new column pcount and in new_count column the numbers associated with pid are summed up.

Comment: Can we see the code you tried and where it failed? And please fix your examples. We can't copy/paste them, they throw errors

Comment: @sotos Sorry for the issue.I havnt tried the code.I can copy paste from the excel. did dname bid Bname rname pid count
109 A 5252 A1 AK 65488 5
109 A 5252 A1 AK 65488 4
201 B 6633 B1 RA 54654 6
521 C 4455 C1 RK 68745 10
521 C 4455 C1 RK 68745 2
521 C 4455 C1 RK 68745 6
111 D 8989 D1 PK 32485 4
111 D 8989 D1 PK 32485 8
111 D 8990 D2 AP 87891 11
111 D 8990 D2 AP 87891 5

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code, using `aggreate()` and `table()`:

```
df.out <- `row.names<-`((r<-aggregate(df[7],df[-7],sum))[order(r$dname),],seq(nrow(r)))
df.out$pcount <- (p <- table(df$pid))[match(df.out$pid,names(p))]
```

which gives

```
> df.out
  did dname  bid bname rname   pid count pcount
1 109     A 5252    A1    AK 65488     9      2
2 201     B 6633    B1    RA 54654     6      1
3 521     C 4455    C1    RK 68745    18      3
4 111     D 8989    D1    PK 32485    12      2
5 111     D 8990    D2    AP 87891    16      2
```

Comment: Hi...this solution is throwing an error...What is r (r<-aggregate...) in this..? Need held..

Comment: @Rahul Did you try my code over the `df` in your post? What's the version of your `R`? Mine is `R 3.6.1`

Comment: @Rahul `(r<-aggregate...)` is to assign the aggregated data frame to variable `r`... I just write it in one line, and you can rewrite it into several line of course. Also, you had errors in your data in your previous post, I corrected it

Comment: I am also using R 3.6.1

Comment: Now the code is working but not showing the desired output....

Comment: @Rahul What is the desired output? I cannot see difference between mine and yours.

Comment: If you see the data rname is basically name .....there can be 2 or more pids associated with rname , of which count is needed as pcount and count column has numbers which is associated with pids and is needed as new_count...So basically if rname has 2 pids with count as 5 and 4 ,the the count associated with rname should be 2 in pcount and in new_count should be 9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203797/discussion-between-rahul-and-thomasiscoding).

Comment: @Rahul Sorry that I did not notice your chat! Now the solution is updated, you can check it out